# python's alsaaudio.mixer not refreshing mixer settings

Tags: python, linux, alsa

i would like to control the mixer of my ALSA soundcard from python. at the same time, i would like to be able to get changes from other applications that might modify the soundcard in parallel.

i guess the simplest way is to use the soundcard's mixer interface to set and *query* the mixer.
that's supposedly fairly easy with the `alsaaudio` package:

```
import alsaaudio
mixer=alsaaudio.Mixer()
print mixer.getvolume() # prints e.g. '[100L]'
mixer.setvolume(50)
print mixer.getvolume() # prints '[50L]'
```

unfortunately, an instance of the `Mixer` doesn't get udpated if the controls change "under the hood".
consider the above application running, but now changes the mixer with something like `alsamixergui` to 80.

```
print mixer.getvolume()  # prints '[50L]'
mixer2=alsaaudio.Mixer()
print mixer2.getvolume() # prints '[80L]'
print mixer.getvolume()  # prints '[50L]'
```

is instantiating a new Mixer() the only way to poll for new mixer settings, or is there a simpler way to refresh the values of an existing instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Mixer.**polldescriptors**() documentation](http://pyalsaaudio.sourceforge.net/libalsaaudio.html#alsaaudio.Mixer.polldescriptors) says:

> Returns a tuple of (file descriptor, eventmask) that can be used to wait for changes on the mixer with *select.poll*.

Comment: thanks; unfortunately i'm still stuck; i can use the polldescriptors to correctly detect whether the controller has changed, but still `mixer.getvolume()` returns the old value. do i have to create a new `Mixer()` (and new `polldescriptor()`s and new `select.poll()`s every time i detect a change on the (old) polldescriptor? that seems like *very* inefficient.

Comment: This appears to be a bug in `alsaaudio`.

Comment: I don't think this is an alsaaudio bug, but some strange form of caching in libasound. See [my gist](https://gist.github.com/kristianlm/06f3adc866bc5e4c63de) in C.

Comment: @kristianlm That program is buggy; it never calls [snd_mixer_handle_events()](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___mixer.html#gae0cfb6b50ec2493281107b0649f87cb8). Apparently, `alsaaudio` [has the same bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/pyalsaaudio/patches/5/).

Comment: gosh, what a nightmare. The documentation says values are cached, but never mentions how to refresh them. I was looking for `flush` and `refresh` procedures, and didn't try `handle_events` because I wasn't using them. Not too impressed with ALSA's documentation.

thanks so much for your help, @CL!

Comment: What about of non-numeric values? Some mixer controls have an enum to display the names of controls.